Help with multi pin connector recommendation
Let me know if this question violates the no specific product rule, but I am hoping someone can suggest a connector for me.
I need a connector/family of connectors with:
at least 6 pins, but not more than 12.
can carry at least 2 amps per pin.
has solder cups big enough for 18 gauge wire.
positive connection like a thread or clip.
6x18 gauge cable strain relief size.
and a perk would be a split style housing/strain relief like a DE-9.
I think my optimal connector would be a 6 pin military style screw on connector from Amphenol, but at ~$60 per connector it might be too expensive for our project as we need 8 separate connections.
What might work for me?

Do they need to be solder cup, or can they be crimped? Crimp terminals are way more common.

It's the companies electrical policy that all wires be soldered even if they are crimped, so I am open to click in style crimp pins, I will just have to also solder the wire into the pin.

There are plenty of options out there, the final choice depends on your requirements: do you want environmental protection, EMI shielding, high speed data, etc.  For "general purpose" low voltage/low speed data, take a look at M12 connectors though 18 AWG wire might be hard to find in a 6+ pin configuration.  Parametric search on Digikey will show you several attractive prospects in your price range.
There's also the MIL-derivative 5015 family of connectors which are probably going to be cheaper than 38999s but they're a real pain to work with.

For up to 8 circuits, consider the DC-8W8 D-sub connector (my site).
There are no D-sub connectors for more than 8 power circuits. Therefore, I suggest you switch to circular connectors. For 12 circuits, consider the Weipu SY21 circular connector (my site).
